# Power Automate Send E-Mail via HTTP Post Error

Tags: sharepoint, http-post, office365, html-email, power-automate

I have set-up an approval workflow where a user gets notified if his / her request has been submitted for approval. The request is submitted via Microsoft Forms, the workflow then takes the submitters e-mail as the "To" for said notification. This is done via a HTTP Post Action so that the e-mail is directly from SharePoint and not me, the process owner.

This works fine for most user e-mails... however there are some cases where this error message pops up:

> {"odata.error":{"code":"-2130242040, Microsoft.SharePoint.SPException","message":{"lang":"en-US","value":"The e-mail message cannot be sent. Make sure the e-mail has a valid recipient."}}}

My action is configured as follows:
[HTTP Post Action Configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JXpz4.png)

The flow successfully retrieves the user's e-mail address but it is not sending it. This happens to roughly 20% of users.

Thank you!

The body of an unsuccessful e-mail HTTP Post:

```
    "body": {
        "status": 400,
        "message": "{\"odata.error\":{\"code\":\"-2130242040, Microsoft.SharePoint.SPException\",\"message\":{\"lang\":\"en-US\",\"value\":\"The e-mail message cannot be sent. Make sure the e-mail has a valid recipient.\"}}}\r\nclientRequestId: xyz\r\nserviceRequestId: xyz",
        "source": "https://www.sharepoint.com/Teams/Team_Name/_api/SP.Utilities.Utility.SendEmail",
        "errors": []
    }
}
```

Successful HTTP Post:

```
{
  "odata.null": true
}
```

Comment: Can you share [in your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/70542512/edit) what's the value of request's `Body`? How is it different from the successful ones? Of course, please redact any personal information before.

Comment: So if it's working for most people, can you isolate some of the email addresses that it's not, and see if there's a pattern in those addresses? Perhaps it's a character in their address that the script is choking on?

Comment: @Nathan its a big organisation with a standard e-mail format. The users that work have the exact same formating as the ones that don't work... which is very confusing. Could it be something with different system languages?!